# Why does my UIImageView replace the second one?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, imageview

I have two outlets for two different UIImageViews, when I select the first one it'll appear on the first Image View but when I select the second Image, it replaces the first Image View even though it's connected to the second ImageView. This is my code for the Select Image button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView2: UIImageView!


@IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: Any) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
}

//Add didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo here
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView1.image = image
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func pickImage2(_ sender: Any) {
    let image2 = UIImagePickerController()
    image2.delegate = self
    image2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image2.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image2, animated: true)
}

//Add didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo here
func imagePickerController2(_ picker2: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo2 info2: [String : Any]) {
    if let image2 = info2[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView2.image = image2
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: if you rename the delegate method, as you did in the second call it will no longer be recognized or called.

Comment: @BJHStudios Your explanation of the cause of the problem should be in your answer.

Comment: @rmaddy done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. So you need a flag to remember which image view is clicked, and then set image base on that.

```
var selected = 1

@IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: Any) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 1

    self.present(image, animated: true)
}

//Add didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo here
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if selected == 1 {
            myImageView1.image = image
        } else {
            myImageView2.image = image
        }
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func pickImage2(_ sender: Any) {
    let image2 = UIImagePickerController()
    image2.delegate = self
    image2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image2.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 2

    self.present(image2, animated: true)
}
```

Moving forward, when you have multiple image views, you can use another method to avoid copying code everywhere.

First, add an unique tag for each image view. Avoid using 0 because the default tag is 0. So you will have image views with tags say 1 to 4.

Call this same method to all your image views so that this function is trigger by clicking on any of them

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Handler looks like this

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    selected = tappedImage.tag
    self.present(image, animated: true)
}
```

Finally in image pick delegate

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if let imageView = self.view.viewWithTag(selected) as? UIImageView {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: While this is a correct solution, to make this answer better, explain the problem in the OP's code.

Comment: Instead of adding the `selected` property as an `Int`, why not have a `var selectedImageView: UIImageView?` property. Set that in the two `pickImageX` methods. Then in the delegate, directly assign the selected image to the property. No need for the `if`.

Comment: hey, what do I do if I want to add additional images like 3 or 4?

Comment: @Riccardo Updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have renamed the delegate method. If you do that, the method won't be recognized or called.

Another option to the selected answer is to extend `UIImageView` and have it adhere to `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` / `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

```
extension UIImageView: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

     public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
          guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
             //handle error
             return
         }

         image = selectedImage
         picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
     }

     func presentImagePicker(from viewController: UIViewController) {
         let picker = UIImagePickerController()
         picker.delegate = self
         picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
         picker.allowsEditing = false

         viewController.present(picker, animated: true)
     }
}
```

This is nice because you can then launch the image picker for any `UIImageView` in your app with one line, like so:

```
@IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myImageView1.presentImagePicker(from: self)
}
```